# ''Cannot find module" issues with Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

When using the "ionic serve" command on a recently generated application I am met with an error

```
[ng] The system cannot find the path specified.
[ng] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
[ng]   throw err;
[ng]   ^
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\shane\College\Year 2\Semester 2\Mobile Application Development\Ionic\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
[ng]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
[ng]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
[ng]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[ng]   requireStack: []
[ng] }

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

I have tried to uninstall node.js, the angular/cli and cordova ionic many times with fresh installs but nothing seems to work. I am lost to where I go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error said that set the environment variable
install the latest npm package globally

> npm install -g npm@latest

```
second thing is you follow this   
Option 1: edit your Windows installation's PATH to put %appdata%\npm before %ProgramFiles%\nodejs.   Remember that you'll need to restart cmd.exe (and potentially restart Windows) when you make changes to PATH or how npm is installed.

Option 2: remove both of

%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm
%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd
```